# Sharepoint 2010 : How to set a default value for a "image" type List column

Tags: list, publishing, column

I have a Sharepoint List column named "Thumbnail".

Type: Publishing Image
Status: Optional.

How to set a default image value for this column ?

Answer (score 3):

The Publishing Image unfortunately does not support a default value.